# Is there a difference between these two conversion methods?

Tags: c++, templates

I have to work with some heavily templated code which I am trying to decipher.

I see two different constructs and I am not sure if I am missing something. Here is a simplified example of these type conversions which are used at some places, is there a difference between the following statements?

```
template<typename T, typename S> S my_function(T t) 
{
    // version 1:
    S s = t
    return s;

    // version 2:
    return S(t);
 }
```

I am thinking to changing everything to one style, are the two statements 100% equivalent and if not, what are the differences?

Comment: Use `function` as the name is a bad practice.

Comment: With compiler optimization, I think so, but am not 100% sure.

Comment: You probably want to swap the template parameter positions for `T` and `S` so you can use `function<S>` with `T` deduced instead of having to write `function<T, S>`.

Comment: For `T == int *` and `S == double *` version 1 will fail because incompatible types and version 2 will compile because C cast.

Comment: I feel the answer can also vary greatly between [tag:c++17] and [tag:c++14]. A proper tagging may help focus the effort in answering.

Comment: @StoryTeller A complete answer would be a bunch of if-elses. So I just throw in the relevant cppref pages for the OP to figure out the if-elses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they are not 100% equivalent!

For the simple case (c++11 and beyond), considering the return statement with type `class S` then the difference are:

If `S` has [move operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment) then they are used when returning the value, otherwise the [copy operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment) are used. Also note that if those operators are private or deleted then version 1 will not compile.

For version 2 `s` is created (with a constructor, or user defined operator) and returned directly because of [RVO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization)

Now for the complicated case, there are other things to consider; First version uses [copy initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) and second is [direct initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization). There are also [user defined operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) and [explicit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit) keyword that can alter the behavior.

Comment: After that, I turn to Python ultimately XD

Comment: `S` and `T` might even be the same class, then it depends on the class implementation and used semantics: copy, move, function call operator, etc.

Comment: The answer should be "No, they are not 100% equivalent, it might be depending on the use case".

Answer (score 1):

Version 1 and 2 are called [copy initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) (form 1) and [direct initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization) (form 3), respectively. The difference depends on the relationship between `T` and `S`.

The effects on the `return` statement, which performs copy initialization (form 4), depend on the nature of `S`. The difference is that `s` is an l-value while `S(t)` is an r-value. [Copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) may also apply here. For class types, this may make a difference.

Comment: There should be a note about RVO and Move operators, considering the return staments.

Comment: It is not that simple. `S(t)` is equivalent to `(S)t` iff `S` does not have constructors.

Comment: Version 2 might also fall in function call operator overload `operator()`